# HTML Data Attribute Can't Be Updated By Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML button :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a id="TopBiggestCommissionButton" href="#" 
           class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-paging="0">More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I have this jquery to update the `data-paging` attribute :

```
$( "#TopBiggestCommissionButton" ).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var paging = $(this).attr("data-paging");
    paging = parseInt(paging) + parseInt(10);
    alert (paging); //--- THIS PRODUCE 10 as result
    $(this).data("paging", paging); //--- but this isn't working
});
```

why I still have `0` as `data-paging` value when I view the source code. not `10`. thank you.

Comment: The source code never changes. Your code is working fine. jQuery stores changes to `data` attributes in an internal cache for better performance. You could use `attr('data-paging', paging)` to set the attribute and make the change visible in the DOM inspector, but this is not necessarily required and slower

Comment: the source code does not change when you update a `data-attribute` via .data() method. rather, jQuery cached the data internally. checking the value in the console would give you 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.data()` use internal cache to store information, it doesn't update attributes. If you want to update attribute use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2)

```
$(this).attr("data-paging", paging);
```

You don't need to use `.attr()`just use `.data()` while reading and writing `paging` data

```
$( "#TopBiggestCommissionButton" ).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var paging = $(this).data("paging");
    paging += 10;
    alert (paging); 
    $(this).data("paging", paging); 
});
```